# Get calling method's gameobject information

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a custom script attached to a Gameobject as a component
say it's Gameobject G1 with a component C1

In component C1, it has a method to call another Gameobject (G2)' and set its active to false
The Gameobject G2 has another component script C2, in this script, in the OnEnable() method, I'm trying to get the calling script's Gameobject so I can reference it.

I have tried to use reflection, something like

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod().
```

I can get the calling method name, reflectType but I couldn't reference the actual Gameobject (G1)
Any other way that I can achieve this request? tks

FYI, the reason I can't simply use parameter is that the (G1 and C1) are third party script that I have downloaded from Assetstore, I just don't want to modify its source code, and unfortunately that calling method is not an override method.

**To answer some comments below:**

The component (C1) is a third party script from assetstore, I can edit it for sure but I rather not to, because this C1 could be updated from the author by next updates, and it is hard to follow.

The C1 has a public field to assign a "Gameobject", and it has a private method to call that Gameobject's "SetActive" function.

For instance, I'm dragging the G2 to that field, so the C1 private method can SetActive(true) to it whenever it is necessary.

The problem is in that, in that asset plugin, there are so many gameobjects has this C1 script attached, and my design is drag my G2 gameobject to each of that script's public field.

And then only if I can get a reference from G2>C2 to determine which gameobject's C1 is calling

Hope I explain this well, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add a field/property publicly editable to `C2` then edit `C1` to set it on the component if it exists: `if (target.TryGetComponent(out C2 otherComponent)){C2.activatorGameobject = gameObject;}`

Comment: How is C1 calling C2? Is it a UnityEvent? Why are you not adding a field to C2 that references C1? It's a bit unclear what and why.

Comment: It sounds like you would just be better off with a static controller or extension that you call rather than the object directly. passing both the caller and the recipient to said controller or extension and use that to then make the actions you need by passing along the gameobject to c2 before deactivating g2